# How to use setuptools_scm?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

I didn't quite understand how to use `setuptools-scm`.

From what I understand, this tool should derive a version number according to the SCM (git in my case) history. It basically uses the distance from the latest tag in order to derive this information.

Now, say I have a project in which we work as such: we have a `main` and `develop` branches. We work with SemVer, so we have a `x.y.z` version schema. Now, whenever we commit to `develop`, we'd like to have a latest package in our package registry. So if the latest version on the main branch is `1.2.3` for example, we'd like to get `1.2.3.dev1`, `1.2.3.dev2`, etc.

What I actually see happening is, that if I have `1.2.3` as my latest tag, setuptools-scm defines the next version as `1.2.4`, plus, it adds a `+g532hj..` to the version, which a registry such as `PyPI Test` for example doesn't accept.

Could someone explain exactly how is it used?

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, that behavior from `setuptools-scm` it's surprising and hard to understand, while the doc doesn't give it (in my opinion) proper emphasis, it's documented [right there](https://setuptools-scm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#default-versioning-scheme).

The thing is, `setuptools-scm` get the current version *if you're in a tagged commit*, when you're not (most of the time) it tries very hard to "guess" the next version dividing it in two parts, the "version" and the "local" part, with the format `{version}+{local}`, both of them [can be configured](https://setuptools-scm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending/#version-number-construction).

The `{version}` part is controlled by the `version_scheme` directive, which by default:

> Automatically guesses the next development version (default). Guesses
> the upcoming release by incrementing the pre-release segment if
> present, otherwise by incrementing the micro segment. Then appends
> .devN. In case the tag ends with .dev0 the version is not bumped and
> custom .devN versions will trigger a error.

The `{local}` part is controlled by the `local_scheme` directive, which by default:

> adds the node on dev versions and the date on dirty workdir (default)

Unfortunately there isn't a value of `version_scheme` which does *exactly* what you want (add a plain `.devX`) but you can get away with one of these:

- `post-release`

> generates post release versions (adds .postN)

- `no-guess-dev`

> Does no next version guessing, just adds .post1.devN

About the `{local}` part you can disable it completely using in `local_scheme` the value `no-local-version`.

> omits local version, useful e.g. because pypi does not support it

Hope this helps.

**Edit**: Sorry, my first post was quite incomplete since I completely missed the `local_scheme` part at first.